# Using beautiful soup regex in a large HTML file python

Tags: python, html, regex

I can't find the answer to this specific question anywhere and I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

I have a large HTML file which is the template for an email. I have read this in as a text file and saved the value in variable html_string I have several lines throughout containing statements such as

```
<span style="color: #ff0000;"> {column_1}</span>

<span style="color: #ff0000;">{column_2}</span>
```

where the {column_*} parts will be replaced by some other value such as a name. Another question suggested using something such as

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, features="html5lib")

    target = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('^{column_$'))

    print("Target:")
    print(target)

    for v in target:
        # do something (this never gets accessed due to empty list)
```

which returns

```
   >>Target:
   >> []
```

whereas I hoped it would return a list of the location of the {column_*} or something else that I could use to insert my own strings.

I have tried several different structures for the re.compile(x) part but nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT------
For some reason even though I have bs4 imported, only the findAll function will perform what I require - it is generally advised not to use this as find_all in bs4 will "do the same thing" ¬(..)¬

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, features="html5lib")
    target = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('{column_.}'))

    for v in target:
        v.replace_with(dictionary[str(v)])

    body = str(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the templating and replace the text with the desired values:

```
import re
vals = {'column_1':'Name', 'column_2':'Age'}
result = re.sub('\{.*?\}', lambda x:vals[x.group()[1:-1]], content)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
<span style="color: #ff0000;"> Name</span>

<span style="color: #ff0000;">Age</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a dict as well?

```
html  = '''
<span style="color: #ff0000;">column_1</span>
<span style="color: #ff0000;">column_2</span>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
dict = {'column_1':'Name', 'column_2':'Age'}

for item in soup.select('[style="color: #ff0000;"]'):
    try:
        item.string = dict[item.text]
    except:
        continue
print(soup)
```